# what is the difference between run spring boot Application class and run it in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

My colleague create a spring boot project used `2.0.0.M7`, when I run the project by run Application class in idea it cloud be *stopped* successfully, but if I run it in tomcat(war exploded)

[image]

in this case when I *stop* it I always get below error

```
Exception in thread "scheduler_Worker-7" Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.core.status.WarnStatus]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1293)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/status/WarnStatus
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.noAppenderDefinedWarning(LoggerContext.java:186)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:264)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.debug(Logger.java:482)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:612)
```

So what the difference between run Application class and run Tomcat, why run Tomcat could have the additional error when stop it?

In additional in very rare situation it also could be stopped successfully.

Comment: What is JDK version?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has 2 parts.

**Part 1: Running options**

When you run by Tomcat (as you seen yellow Tom cat icon), you run/debug application on local/remote **real server**.

When you run by SpringBootApplication, it mean, fat JAR (executable JAR, with **embedded Apache Tomcat 8.5.x server**).

**Part 2: Error what related Logback**

Add dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Let's me know what happen after apply the above solutions.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't think it's related with `logback`, please note this sentence `this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.core.status.WarnStatus].`